# How to pass multiple parameters to mvc controller using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a controller with parameters of different types (model, array, string and int)
Something like this.

```
public JsonResult UpdateDemandeur(Demandeurs ddeur, Photos vImg, Array vRev, Array vLangAut, int vLangMater)
```

I want to POST my data thru AJAX call and I used something of this kind:

```js
                var json = JSON.stringify({
                    'ddeur': {
                        ID_Ville: xIDVille,
                        ID_Province: xIDProv,
                        CodePostal_Demandeur: xCPDdeur,
                        Tel1_Demandeur: xTel1Ddeur,
                        Tel2_Demandeur: xTel2Ddeur,
                        Tel3_Demandeur: xTel3Ddeur,
                        Courriel1_Demandeur: xCour1Ddeur,
                        Courriel2_Demandeur: xCour2Ddeur,
                        Courriel3_Demandeur: xCour3Ddeur,
                        Code_Conseiller: xCodeCons,
                        ID_SituationMatrimoniale: xIDSitMat,
                        ID_Sexe: xIDSexe,
                        Date_Naissance_Demandeur: xDteNais,
                        ID_TranchesRevenu: xRevDdeur,
                        ID_Occupation: xIDOcc,
                        ID_Scolarite: xIDScol,
                        ID_StatutLegal: xIDStatLegal,
                        ID_Communaute: xIDComm,
                        ID_SourceInformation: xIDSceInfo,
                        Handicape: xHandicape,
                        Reference: xRef,
                        Remarques_Demandeur: xRemDdeur,
                        Date_Cloture_Dossier: xDtClotureDos,
                        Actif_Inactif: xInActif,
                        Dte_Saisie: xDteSaisie,
                        UserId: xUsrID

                    },
                    'vImg': {
                        Nom_Table: 'Demandeurs',
                        Photo: resp
                    }
                  ...
                });

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../Conseiller/UpdateDemandeur",
                    data: json,
                    dataType: "json",
                  ...
```

As you can see on the screenshot, my variables at the controller side come empty with no error... I have tried several things but it's been a headache since.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RESW8.png)

Comment: You have not set the necessary `contentType: 'contentType: application/json,'` option (and not related,  but use `url: '@Url.Action("UpdateDemandeur", "Conseiller")',` - always use `Url.Action()` to generate the correct url)

Comment: And you might want to consider accepting answers in your previous question that solved you problems.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to stringify it.. just pass an array of objects like so:

```
var json = [
                {
                    ID_Ville: xIDVille,
                    ID_Province: xIDProv,
                    CodePostal_Demandeur: xCPDdeur,
                    Tel1_Demandeur: xTel1Ddeur,
                    Tel2_Demandeur: xTel2Ddeur,
                    Tel3_Demandeur: xTel3Ddeur,
                    Courriel1_Demandeur: xCour1Ddeur,
                    Courriel2_Demandeur: xCour2Ddeur,
                    Courriel3_Demandeur: xCour3Ddeur,
                    Code_Conseiller: xCodeCons,
                    ID_SituationMatrimoniale: xIDSitMat,
                    ID_Sexe: xIDSexe,
                    Date_Naissance_Demandeur: xDteNais,
                    ID_TranchesRevenu: xRevDdeur,
                    ID_Occupation: xIDOcc,
                    ID_Scolarite: xIDScol,
                    ID_StatutLegal: xIDStatLegal,
                    ID_Communaute: xIDComm,
                    ID_SourceInformation: xIDSceInfo,
                    Handicape: xHandicape,
                    Reference: xRef,
                    Remarques_Demandeur: xRemDdeur,
                    Date_Cloture_Dossier: xDtClotureDos,
                    Actif_Inactif: xInActif,
                    Dte_Saisie: xDteSaisie,
                    UserId: xUsrID

                },
                {
                    Nom_Table: 'Demandeurs',
                    Photo: resp
                }
              ...
            ];

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "../Conseiller/UpdateDemandeur",
                data: json,
                dataType: "json",
              ...
```

Comment: Also, you didn't post the class definitions for the objects on the c# side, and I assumed that the members all match.  That's important.

Comment: Hello Jay,
Just did so, but still get same result.
My controller parameters are not filled out

Comment: I will check the models, but I doubt, cause I tried each parameter by itself and I get the result I want.

Comment: Just guessing now, but try passing an array of objects: var data = [ { ddeur object goes here }, { vImg object goes here } ];

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could by pass was to define all my parameters in the data part of the AJAX call.
Like this:

```js
 $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../Conseiller/UpdateDemandeur",
                    data: {
                        Adresse_Demandeur: xAddDdeur,
                        ID_Ville: xIDVille,
                        ID_Province: xIDProv,
                        CodePostal_Demandeur: xCPDdeur,
                        Tel1_Demandeur: xTel1Ddeur,
                        Tel2_Demandeur: xTel2Ddeur,
                        Tel3_Demandeur: xTel3Ddeur,
                        Courriel1_Demandeur: xCour1Ddeur,
                        Courriel2_Demandeur: xCour2Ddeur,
                        Courriel3_Demandeur: xCour3Ddeur,
                        Code_Conseiller: xCodeCons,
                        ID_SituationMatrimoniale: xIDSitMat,
                        ID_Sexe: xIDSexe,
                        Date_Naissance_Demandeur: xDteNais,
                        ID_TranchesRevenu: xRevDdeur,
                        ID_Occupation: xIDOcc,
                        ID_Scolarite: xIDScol,
                        ID_StatutLegal: xIDStatLegal,
                        ID_Communaute: xIDComm,
                        ID_SourceInformation: xIDSceInfo,
                        Handicape: xHandicape,
                        Reference: xRef,
                        Remarques_Demandeur: xRemDdeur,
                        Date_Cloture_Dossier: xDtClotureDos,
                        Actif_Inactif: xInActif,
                        Dte_Saisie: xDteSaisie,
                        UserId: xUsrID,

                        Nom_Table: xTable,  //(varchar(50), not null)
                        Photo: null, //(varbinary(max)2147483647)
                        Nom_Fichier_Photo: resp, //(varchar(max), null)
                        Remarques_Photo: null,  //(varchar(max), null)

                    },
                    dataType: "json",...
```

All of my parameters type were thus correctly evaluated.
I know this not coding(with this, I'm sure to encounter a bottle neck somewhere soon), so if someone can help sort this out, it'd be fun.